# Wake Up Agent Python 2.7 script

Tags: python, mcafee

So using the McAfee book "epo_510_rg_Web API_0-00_en-us" I have attemped to implement the Example 2 script for waking up agents on page 22...  Anyway I receive the below error:

```
    C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\test\venv\Scripts\python.exe 
    C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/test/autoAgentWakeUp.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/test/autoAgentWakeUp.py", line 14, in <module>
    result = mc.system.wakeupAgent(id)
    File "C:\Python27\Lib\mcafee.py", line 446, in __call__
    return self.invoker.invoke(self.prefix + '.' + self.name, argmap)
    File "C:\Python27\Lib\mcafee.py", line 271, in invoke
    if arg[:8] == 'file:///':
    TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Anyway below is my code, I suspect the error is probably due to using ePO 5.3 over ePO 5.1:

```
    import mcafee
    import ssl
    ssl.match_hostname= lambda cert, hostname: True
    mc = mcafee.client("localhost", "8443","admin","password")


    #code specific to this task
    input = "mytag" #

    systems = mc.system.find(input)#Search text can be IP address, MAC address, user 
    name, agent GUID or tag
    #The above uses the System Tree for searching
    for system in systems:
    id = system['EPOComputerProperties.ParentID']
    result = mc.system.wakeupAgent(id)
```

Anyway I will continue looking into this error and  see if I can find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I have managed to solve my own problem just after posting here.  Anyway for some reason or another:

```
    EPOComputerProperties.ParentID
```

Will not work, so instead I called on the devices IP address, yes it was really stupid but it works so I'm happy:

```
    id = system['EPOComputerProperties.ParentID']
```

So replace the above line with the below line

```
    id = system['EPOComputerProperties.IPAddress']
```